# Cannot update or delete row in MySQL due to key column not being recognised

Tags: mysql

If I try to update or delete one of my tables in my database (and only that table), I cannot do so without enabling safe mode.

Query:

`UPDATE booking SET bookingDate='2017-09-20' WHERE id=123456;`

Error:

> Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column

The problem with that error message is that I do actually have a primary key which is an index and I was trying to use it to update the row, but for some reason my database just doesn't recognise it. I only have that problem on one specific table as well.

I understand that I could turn off safe updates every time that I want to run an update or delete a row, but that isn't what I want to do as I shouldn't have to do that with a primary key present.

I have tried dropping the table and rebuilding it, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Do you have a trigger running on that table?

Comment: Have you tried temporarily disabling the key constraints whilst you update the table?

Comment: I do have a trigger running after an update, but in the query I was running above, it wouldn't do anything as it checking for a different column that isn't affected.

Comment: Disabling the key constraints didn't do much (` SET autocommit=0; SET unique_checks=0; SET foreign_key_checks=0;`) for me in InnoDB, it is still insisting that I will have to disable safe mode.

Comment: No semi colon(;) at the end of this code. Is it present on your database code?

Comment: The semi colon is in my database code, it just didn't copy for some reason, I will edit it back in.

Comment: To clarify, is `id` your primary key column in that table?

Comment: Yes, that is the primary key.

Comment: If that's true then you shouldn't be getting this error. can you post the table definition please? (e.g. in the form of a CREATE TABLE statement - you can script it out from MySQL Workbench for instance)

Comment: What about the size and datatype of that column

Comment: @ADyson `CREATE TABLE booking (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  bookingDate date NOT NULL,
  paid enum('Y','N') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;`